# React native base input prefix

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I use native base in my react native application.
I am not sure how to make a prefix in the input field?!
Basically want to have a placeholder, and add a prefix when user starts typing in.
Backend expect userID with a @ prefix.
I want a placeholder to present when the input is empty and add the @ prefix when typing.
What is the solution for this?